# set method in linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have trouble shooted this to a point where i'm not sure where to go anymore. I have narrowed it down to the set() method. When i run this on a windows machine it works fine. However it needs to run on linux. When doing this nothing is getting stored in the compareset variable.

**This is the code that uses the set() method.**

```
def three_way_compare(startup, running, archive):
    isdiff = True

    print "Running Three-Way Comparison."

    if cmp(startup, archive) and cmp(running, archive) != 0:
        print "Archive File(s) Missing:"
        compareset = sorted(set(startup)^set(archive))
    elif cmp(startup, archive) != 0:
        print "Startup File(s) Missing:" 
        compareset = sorted(set(startup)^set(archive))
    elif cmp(running, archive) != 0:
        print "Running File(s) Missing:"
        compareset = sorted(set(running)^set(archive))
    elif cmp(running, startup) != 0:
        print "Running and Startup do not match"
        compareset = sorted(set(running)^set(startup))
    else:
        print "All Files Exist" 
        isdiff = False
    if isdiff == True:
        from sendmail import send_mail
        #write_diff_file(compareset)
        print compareset
```

On a windows machine the compareset variable stores all the different elements and it displays, However it does not on linux, just shows the following. On windows the [] is filled with all the different elements.

> Running Three-Way Comparison. Startup File(s) Missing: [] Comparison
>   Finished.

I'm still new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

**Here is the Parse method.**

```
def parse_files(directory):
    results = []
    i = 0
    l = len(os.listdir(directory))
    #os.chdir(directory)
    try:
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
                file_name = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                    for line in in_file:
                        match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                        if match:
                            results.append(match.group(1))
                            #print "Match Found"

            sleep(0.001)
            i += 1
            progress_bar(i, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', barLength = 50)
        return results
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
        print "Error in parse_files function"
```

Comment: What's with the `!= 0`? There's no need for it, non-zero values are already true.

Comment: My thought there was that cmp() returns 1 or -1 if they different and 0 if they are the same. I was saying there that if the cmp is not the same return true. But maybe that thinking in java? I'm still very new. I didn't know how else to right it.

Comment: Please post the complete error, including stack trace telling which line the error occurs. Also, can you tell us what your goal is for this function?

Comment: It's true that `cmp` does not return a boolean value, but the `if` statement treats it as one. Also if you're just checking that the variables are different why are you using `cmp(x, y)` instead of a plain `x != y`? Not to mention that the `cmp` function is gone in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu you are correct. a simple x != y does work. The issue is still with the set() method. Works on windows, but not linux. is there another way to get the elements in a list that are not in another list? Esentially what i want to do is compare two lists, then store the differences of those two lists so that i can then save it to a file.

Comment: Well. I think `three_way_compare` is **not** the right place to search for an issue (although it could be written better). It will work exactly the same on windows and on linux. I think the problem is that you pass different sets/lists to `startup`, `running` and `archive` variables depending on system. You can check that by printing these 3 variables in first line of `three_way_compare` method: `print '%s, %s, %s' %(startup, running, archive)`

Comment: @running.t on windows 

['19-sna-r2', '19-sna-r2', '19-testdpn-r1'], ['19-30', '19-sna-r2', '19-sna-r2',
 '19-testdpn-r1'], ['19-30', '19-sna-r2', '19-sna-r2', '19-testdpn-r1']
Running Three-Way Comparison.
Startup File(s) Missing:
['19-30']
Comparison Finished.


on linux
[], [], []
Running Three-Way Comparison.
All Files Exist
Comparison Finished.

Comment: So here is the proof that I was right. On linux you compare empty lists. You should search for an error in the place where these 3 lists are create, not in `three_way_compare` method.

Comment: @NineTail, ...if you had tried to make your code a MCVE -- including the smallest possible complete set of information and code needed for someone to reproduce and test the problem inside the question itself, **including sample data**, you would have observed that the problem is not actually platform-specific, or involved with `set` at all. In the future, please try to follow the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve when asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I found through more troubleshooting was actually the REGEX expression. I removed the ^ and $ and it worked after running it through regex101

**Here is my Parse method.**

```
def parse_files(directory):
    results = []
    i = 0
    l = len(os.listdir(directory))
    #os.chdir(directory)
    try:
        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
                file_name = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                    for line in in_file:
                        match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                        if match:
                            results.append(match.group(1))
                            #print "Match Found"

            sleep(0.001)
            i += 1
            progress_bar(i, l, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', barLength = 50)
        return results
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
        print "Error in parse_files function"
```

**Changes**

```
match = re.search('hostname\s(\S+)', line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in `three_way_compare` method, although it could be written better. This method will work exactly the same on windows and on linux.

I think the problem is that you pass different sets/lists to `startup`, `running` and `archive` variables depending on system. You can check that by printing these 3 variables in first line of `three_way_compare` method:

```
print '%s, %s, %s' %(startup, running, archive)
```

Please look at the way you are collecting data for these 3 lists. I suppose you are using some windows-specific system operation to collect all items in `startup`, `running` and `archive` list.

Comment: so it's with the parse method i have. I do believe this is correct.

Comment: I think the problem is with the regex. I've added several print statements and it is opening the file but does not appear to be finding any matches. This is odd as i'm using the same files on windows as i am on linux.